# issue with alert box in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript, I was creating a form and taking the value from the text box but to cross-check it whether the value is fetched, I used alert inside my js code. it is not showing any alert box while running the code.

I tried to use it without form tag it was working fine.

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Alert</h2>
<form name="myForm" action="thanks.html" method="get">
       UserName:<br/><input type="text" name="user"><br/><br/>
       Email:<br/><input type="text" name="pass" id="email"><br/><br/>
       Message:<br/><textarea name="msg" rows="5"></textarea><br/><br/>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" onsubmit="validate()">

    </form>

<script>
function validate(){
var email= document.getElementById("email").value;
alert(email);

}

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

can you please tell me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

`input` element doesn't have `onSubmit` event but `form` does.

That's all you need to change:

```
<form name="myForm" action="thanks.html" method="get" onsubmit="validate()">
```

**Demo:**

```js
function validate() {
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  alert(email);
}
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Alert</h2>
<form name="myForm" action="thanks.html" method="get" onsubmit="validate()">
  UserName:<br/><input type="text" name="user"><br/><br/> Email:
  <br/><input type="text" name="pass" id="email"><br/><br/> Message:
  <br/><textarea name="msg" rows="5"></textarea><br/><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">

</form>
```

Comment: with the visual studio code, i made the preferred changes but it is again not working and rather redirecting it to the next success page.

Comment: i tried your code on codepen it is working fine. Is there any issue with Visual Studio?

Comment: when a `form` is trigger, it will redirect you. you need to call `preventDefault` on the `event` object that is pass to `validate` as first argument. see [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Answer (score 0):

Change the inout type from "submit" to "button" and then submit your form from validate function using $("#form_id").submit()
Also you can try adding e.preventDefault() in validate function.

Answer (score 0):

input has no onSubmit event but form has

```js
function validate(){
var email= document.getElementById("email").value;
alert(email);

}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Alert</h2>
<form name="myForm" action="thanks.html" method="get" onsubmit="validate()">
       UserName:<br/><input type="text" name="user"><br/><br/>
       Email:<br/><input type="text" name="pass" id="email"><br/><br/>
       Message:<br/><textarea name="msg" rows="5"></textarea><br/><br/>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" >

    </form>
\



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onsubmit="validate()"` function in form tag instead input type submit.

```
<html>
<body>
    <h2>JavaScript Alert</h2>
    <form name="myForm" action="thanks.html" method="get" onsubmit="validate()">
       UserName:<br/><input type="text" name="user"><br/><br/>
       Email:<br/><input type="text" name="pass" id="email"><br/><br/>
       Message:<br/><textarea name="msg" rows="5"></textarea><br/><br/>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">
    </form>
<script>
    function validate() {
        var email= document.getElementById( "email" ).value;
        alert( email );
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```